# Java file channel exceptions

Tags: java, exception, filesystems

When using a file channel to copy a file in Java, when copying to another drive will an exception be thrown if there is not enough space on the disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it will: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long, long, java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)

*This answer may be wrong, because you did not include any code, how you use the FileChannel.*

Read this article: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0064.html